# UISwipeGestureRecognizer Not Performing Method

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uitapgesturerecognizer, uiswipegesturerecognizer

I am having a difficult time getting a Swipe Gesture Recognizer to work on my app.  Here is the Hierarchy of it all.

App's root view is a `UINavigationController` which has class `ViewController` as visible for the first view seen.  I have a `UIButton` which will fire a movie that loops until I tap it twice which will have the navigation controller push a new ViewController that I have made called PUPPETS1 onto the screen.  This VC has its own xib.  The xib has a `UIImageView`.  What I want to have happen is to start playing a movie once I swipe up on the screen, but that never happens, and the console never shows my NSLog from the 2nd VC's method.

```
- (void)loopVideo {

    NSURL *videoURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"warpspeed" withExtension:@"mov"];
    UIView *patternView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
    patternView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    [self.moviePlayer2.backgroundView addSubview:patternView];
    self.moviePlayer2 = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:videoURL];
    [self.moviePlayer2 setControlStyle:MPMovieControlStyleDefault];

    self.moviePlayer2.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleNone;
    self.moviePlayer2.scalingMode = MPMovieScalingModeAspectFill;
    self.moviePlayer2.movieSourceType = MPMovieSourceTypeFile;
    [self.moviePlayer2 setAllowsAirPlay:YES];
    self.moviePlayer2.view.frame = self.view.frame;


    UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGesture = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(puppetOne)];
    tapGesture.numberOfTapsRequired = 2;
    tapGesture.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1;

    UIView *aView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:self.moviePlayer2.backgroundView.bounds];
    [aView addGestureRecognizer:tapGesture];

    [self.view.window addSubview:aView];
    [self.view addSubview:self.moviePlayer2.view];
    self.moviePlayer2.repeatMode = MPMovieRepeatModeOne;
    [self.moviePlayer2 play];

}
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer{

    return YES;

}
```

In the 2nd VC, the PUPPETS1 one:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewWillAppear:YES];
    UISwipeGestureRecognizer * swipeRec = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(playPuppets)];

    swipeRec.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionUp;


     UIView *aView2 = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
    [aView2 addGestureRecognizer:swipeRec];
    [self.view addSubview:aView2];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
}




-(void)playPuppets {
    NSLog(@"PLAYING");
    NSURL *videoURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"SundayPuppets" withExtension:@"m4v"];

    //filePath may be from the Bundle or from the Saved file Directory, it is just the path for the video
    AVPlayer *player = [AVPlayer playerWithURL:videoURL];
    AVPlayerViewController *playerViewController = [AVPlayerViewController new];
    playerViewController.player = player;
    //[playerViewController.player play];//Used to Play On start
    [self presentViewController:playerViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
}
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer{

    return YES;

}
```

Comment: Why do you have super viewWillAppear :yes in viewDIdLoad ? Are you sure viewDidLoad method is called for your second VC ? [super viewWillAppear:YES]; shud be [super viewDidLoad];

Comment: @TejaNandamuri That was a typo from earlier when I tried viewWillAppear.  I just added an NSLog into the viewDidLoad and it does show in the console.

Comment: try to add gesture recogniser to self.view instead of aView2. I think aView is not properly framed in viewDidLoad

Comment: http://merowing.info/2012/03/how-to-check-if-user-touched-anything-in-your-ios-app/

Comment: @TejaNandamuri Using self.view made no difference

Comment: One thing I did just notice @TejaNandamuri is that if I double tap again, it is STILL trying to call the code from the first VC that I use to push this controller.

Comment: Can you show the code relating to pushing to VC2 ? Also why do you have to tap twice for a button to make it push ?

Comment: @TejaNandamuri I need a double tap on screen because all the app is doing is looping a video until I double tap it to push a view controller. That code is ` self.moviePlayer2 = nil;
    PUPPET1 *sundayPuppet = [[PUPPET1 alloc] init];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:sundayPuppet animated:YES];`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The frame of the view to which you're attaching the gr depends on it's parent view's bounds, and those aren't initialized yet in `viewDidLoad`.
Move the setup to after layout is complete (and tweak it to run just once, on the first layout change), i.e.

```
- (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews {
    [super viewDidLayoutSubviews];

    UIView *swipeView = [self.view viewWithTag:999];
    // only do this if we haven't done it already
    if (!swipeView) {
        // now that self.view.bounds is initialized...
        swipeView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
        swipeView.tag = 999;

        // the rest of your OP setup code is fine, and goes here
        UISwipeGestureRecognizer * swipeRec = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(playPuppets)];
        swipeRec.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionUp;
        [swipeView addGestureRecognizer:swipeRec];

        [self.view addSubview:swipeView];
        NSLog(@"%@", swipeView);
    }
}
```

**EDIT** The code above attached the gesture recognizing view correctly, providing a fix in the second view controller.  It turns out that the other problem was the previous view controller was not properly removing the (deprecated) `MPMoviePlayer`, resulting in touches not functioning on the pushed vc.  The entire reworked ViewController.m can be found in the chat linked below, but the fix for the touches issue was here...

```
- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated { 
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated]; 

    [self.moviePlayer stop]; 
    [self.moviePlayer.view removeFromSuperview]; 
    self.moviePlayer = nil; 
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self]; 
}
```

Comment: Ok, I tried this, with a minor edit (aView2 wasn't declared yet in your answer so I added it in), and added NSLogs.  The NSLogs each fire 3 times, but it still won't recognize the swipe.

Comment: :-) I rejected the edit because `aView2` is not necessary.  My code's `swipeView` serves the identical purpose, just better named (I thought).  Try my solution exactly as suggested, removing the analogous code from viewDidLoad.

Comment: So that last line just change from addSubview:aView2 to swipeView?

Comment: Oh yes.  Did I leave that in there?  Sorry about that. Copy-paste error.   Will edit now.

Comment: Ok, same issue with it, nothing happens.

Comment: Do you mean that an up-swipe does not generate a call to playPuppets:?

Comment: Can you paste the result of the NSLog I just added to the answer?

Comment: <UIView: 0x7f9308e906c0; frame = (0 0; 1024 768); tag = 999; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x7f9308e619f0>; layer = <CALayer: 0x7f9308e14cb0>>

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117357/discussion-between-danh-and-user717452).

Comment: @user717452 -  done.  hope the rest of the project boldly goes well!